# number adder does not appear in responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem switching to responsive mode, **the number adder is hidden, only shown on pc**

[image]

How can I make the adder look also in reponsive design?

```html
<input
    id="product"
    class="form-control"
    type="number"
    min="1"
    max="100"
    value=""
    data-id=""
    data-slug=""
>
```

Comment: Hello, it depends on the browser.. it is usually not there for mobile, i guess because it will look very small and will be unusable. If you are using bootstrap you can check for amount selector in it.

Comment: you want this adder in mobile ?

Comment: This feature is default browser support to input type number. you can custom but default not.

Comment: Like the visual aspect of HTML `select` elements, this is rendered by the browser and can't be customized. As previous answers said, you would probably not want that kind of UI on mobile anyway, as it would lead to a poor user experience.